# Flutter iOS app - testing app upgrade in TestFlight

Tags: android, ios, flutter, upgrade, testflight

I am currently building a flutter app that involves checking if the user has the latest version of the app and prompting them to upgrade if not. On the Android part that's not a problem to test as I can install the apk after downloading it from our servers, my question is regarding the iOS part. I do realize then when the app is released I will use the app store, but I am wondering how will I test this feature before release. When I have my app on TestFlight, is there a way to upgrade this app programmatically from inside my code? Will there be a link to TestFlight app like there is to the app store app so when I can use url_launcher to open it (for testing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To open the TestFlight page for your app, use this URL:

`itms-beta://beta.itunes.apple.com/v1/app/XXX`

Replace `XXX` with your app's ID in the App Store (find it in App Store Connect in the App Information section).